# Change the color of a specific word throughout an HTML page - data from text file (.txt)

Tags: jquery, html, colors

I wish to change the text color of the words Up (green) and Down (red) throughout the entire `HTML` page. However, the data which includes these words is pulled from a text file, and changes. I can't figure out how it would be possible to change the text color when the data is being pulled from outside the `HTML` file.

You can see some attempts I have made with jQuery scripts, but they have been unsuccessful. I know little about jQuery, so there could be mistakes with the scripting.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ping Results</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" > 
</head>
<!-- Styles --> 
<style style="text/css">
body {
  background-image: url("https://designnavigator.daimler.com/files/images/Daimler/basic_elements/Buerstung_Abb_00.png");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>

<body>

<script language="jQuery">
 (function($) {
    var thePage = $("body"); 
    thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/(^.*\b(Down)\b.*)$/igm, 
     '<span style="color:red;font-weight: bold;">$1</span>'));
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<script language="jQuery">
 (function($) {
    var thePage = $("body"); 
    thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/(^.*\b(Up)\b.*)$/igm, 
     '<span style="color:green;font-weight: bold;">$1</span>'));
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<h3>&nbsp; Client Pings - Up or Down</h3>
<div id="list">
    <p><iframe src="Results.txt" frameborder="40" height="500"
        width="95%"></iframe></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works only if the following conditions are met:

- The file loaded in the iFrame is served from the domain ([same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy))
- The text file is actually a html file (or at least the server delivers the text file with a mime type text/html). This is because the iframe will render pure text files with a `<pre>` tag surrounding the text and any tags inside the text will not change colors or anything else.

```js
$('#frame').on('load', function() {
    frame_body = $('#frame').contents().find('body');
    replaced_content = frame_body.html().replace(/\b(down)\b/igm, '<span class="down">$1</span>').replace(/\b(up)\b/igm, '<span class="up">$1</span>');
    frame_body.html(replaced_content);
    frame_body.find('.up').css('color', '#0f0');
    frame_body.find('.down').css('color', '#f00');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" src="text.html"></iframe>
```

What appens:

- Wait on the frame to finish loading.
- Access the body of the iframe.
- Add surrounding span with a class.
- Apply style to used classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but whenever I run the snippet, I get an error 404. Maybe I am missing something, but I can't get this to accomplish what I want to.

Comment: Since the file text.html is not on stackoverflow's server, there is a 404 error. You will have to adapt the code and use it on your server. I tried in on mine, and it works just fine.